# Get action local variables name and value OnException customized filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-filters

Want to retrieve the variable value of action into customized filter

```
  public class TrackError : IExceptionFilter
            {
              public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
                {
                    // How to get the value of X ?????????????????                   
                }
        }
```

Controller :

```
[TrackError]
public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Index()
        {

                int x = 0;

            throw new Exception("XYZ");
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create custom exception and put whatever additional data you need into its properties. Then you catch that exception type in one of your catch blocks within your exception filter.

```
public class ServiceException : Exception, ISerializable
{
        public WhateverType X {get;set;}
        public string Message{get;set;}

        public ServiceException()
        {
            // Add implementation.
        }

        public ServiceException(WhateverType x, string message)
        {
            this.X = x;
            this.Message = message;
        }

        public ServiceException(string message):base(message)
        {
        }

        public ServiceException(string message, Exception inner)
        {
            // Add implementation.
        }

        // This constructor is needed for serialization.
        protected ServiceException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        {
            // Add implementation.
        }
}
```

and then in filter:

```
public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            if (context.Exception is ServiceException)
            {
             //Here you can access (context.Exception as ServiceException).X
            }
}
```

throw your exception like:

```
throw new ServiceException(X, "Your custom message gore here");
```

Comment: still i am not able to get the variable value in filter----- context.Exception.X is giving me an error that System.Exception does not contain a definition for X

Comment: you have to cast your exception to (context.Exception as ServiceException).X

Comment: please tell me other ways to retrieve local variables of action in Exception filter or give me some link to study. Thanks again

Comment: i never use any other way. that's exactly what custom exceptions and exception filters are for.

Comment: but i am not able to get the exact exception message, only one type of message is shown by Context.Exception.Message=>Exception of type 'MVCDemo.Common.ServiceException' was thrown.

Comment: check my updated answer. add one more property 'Message' to your exception definition and then throw it with some message as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this way.

```
int x = 0;
    try
    {


        DoSomethingThatMightFail(s);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) when (Log(ex, "An error occurred", new[]{x,s}))
    {
        // this catch block will never be reached
    }

    ...

    static bool Log(Exception ex, string message, params object[] args)
    {
        Debug.Print(message, args);
        return false;
    }
```